Does a infinite a.p with general modulus always contain a subsequence in which any 2 elements are coprime
Let $A=\{am_1+b, am_2+b, am_3+b,...\}$.
for $a,b$ coprime integers, $a \gt 1$, and $m_i$ being a sequence of strictly increasing positive integers.
Does $A$ always contain an infinite subsequence in which all elements are coprime to each other.
Seems like an Erdös problem to me but I can't find anything in his papers.

What are your thoughts on the problem?

Are you aware of the Dirichlet theorem ?

If the $m_i$ are allowed to be any old sewquence of strictly increasing ppositive integers, then you can choose them so that there is a fixed $d>1$ which divides all the elements of $A$.

@GerryMyerson Actually this answers the question.

The question title and body do not agree. Is $A$ supposed to be an arithmetic progression, as in the title, or can it be any subsequence of an arithmetic progression, as in the body?

@Peter, it answers a question, but I'm not sure it's the question OP really wanted to ask.

Care to engage with the comments, Anti?

If you are considering arbitrary subsequences of arithmetic progressions, as in the body of the question, then the answer is negative. Consider for example, for $a=2$ and $b=3$, the sequence $m_i:=3i$. Then clearly
$$am_i+b=3(2i+1),$$
is divisible by $3$ for all $i\geq1$.
If you are only considering arithmetic progressions, as suggested in the title, then the answer is positive. This follows from Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions, but can be shown with less machinery:
Let $a$ and $b$ be two coprime positive integers and for $n\geq1$ let $a_n:=an+b$. Then of course $\gcd(a,a_n)=1$ for all $n\geq1$, and for all $m,n\geq1$ we see that $\gcd(a_m,a_n)$ divides
$$a_n-a_m=(an+b)-(am+b)=a(n-m),$$
from which it follows that $\gcd(a_m,a_n)$ divides $n-m$.
Let $\{n_1,\ldots,n_k\}$ be a finite set of positive integers so that the integers $a_{n_i}$ are pairwise coprime. Then by the Chinese remainder theorem there exists a positive integer $n_{k+1}$ such that $n_{k+1}\equiv n_i-1 \pmod{a_{n_i}}$. Then $\gcd(a_{n_{k+1}},a_{n_i})$ divides $n_i-n_{k+1}$, where by construction
$$n_i-n_{k+1}\equiv1\pmod{a_{n_i}},$$
from which it follows that $\gcd(a_{n_{k+1}},a_{n_i})=1$ for all $n_i\in\{n_1,\ldots,n_k\}$. This shows that $\{n_1,\ldots,n_k,n_{k+1}\}$ is a larger finite set of positive integers so that the integers $a_{n_i}$ are pairwise coprime.
